# TCP мониторинг подключения приложения

Tags: c#, консоль

Делаю консольное приложение, которое должно проверять подключение к определенному IP и выполнять определенные действия. Как мониторить такое подключение?  Тут выводится список всех исходящих, как отфильтровать и оставить только одно?

```
static void ListAvailableTCPPort(ref ArrayList usedPort)
    {
        IPGlobalProperties ipGlobalProperties = IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties();
        TcpConnectionInformation[] tcpConnInfoArray = ipGlobalProperties.GetActiveTcpConnections();
        IEnumerator myEnum = tcpConnInfoArray.GetEnumerator();

        while (myEnum.MoveNext())
        {
            TcpConnectionInformation TCPInfo = (TcpConnectionInformation)myEnum.Current;
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", TCPInfo.RemoteEndPoint);
            usedPort.Add(TCPInfo.LocalEndPoint.Port);
        }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        ArrayList usedPorts = new ArrayList();
        ListAvailableTCPPort(ref usedPorts);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: по какому критерию вы хотите сортировать?

Comment: `Console.WriteLine("{0}", TCPInfo.RemoteEndPoint);` Исправила вывод данных только на конечный ип:порт.   Хочу выбрать из этого списка только одно соединение(например: 127.0.0.1:53937)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вам необходимо  проверять подключение к определенному IP-адресу,то вы должны фильтровать
 1. поле [RemoteEndPoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.tcpconnectioninformation.remoteendpoint(v=vs.110).aspx) - указывает на IP-адрес и порт TCP-соединения, который вас интересует 
 2. У подключения должно быть состояние([State](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.tcpconnectioninformation.state(v=vs.110).aspx))- *Established*,
    которое означает что соединение установлено и данные могут быть
    отправлены.

Вот пример кода:

```
        static void SearchAvailableTCPConnection(ref ArrayList usedPort, string searchAddress, int searchPort)
        {
            IPGlobalProperties ipGlobalProperties = IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties();
            IPEndPoint filterEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(searchAddress), searchPort);

            TcpConnectionInformation tcpConnInfoArray = ipGlobalProperties.GetActiveTcpConnections().Where(g => g.RemoteEndPoint.Equals(filterEndpoint) && g.State ==TcpState.Established).FirstOrDefault();
            if (tcpConnInfoArray != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Port {0} {1} {2} ", tcpConnInfoArray.LocalEndPoint, tcpConnInfoArray.RemoteEndPoint, tcpConnInfoArray.State);
            }
        }


        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ArrayList usedPorts = new ArrayList();
            SearchAvailableTCPConnection(ref usedPorts, "192.168.0.2", 8090);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

На экран будет выведено сообщение только в том случае, если у нас есть активное TCP-соединение с IP-адресом 192.168.0.2 по порту 8090.

Для конвертации строки IP-адреса в класс [IPAddress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress(v=vs.110).aspx), используем статическую функцию этого класса [Parser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.parse(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @Елизавета, исправил, скобку потерял.

Comment: Нашла подключение скайпа по 223.104.3.150:62866, `SearchAvailableTCPPort(ref usedPorts, "223.104.3.150", 62866);`   консоль молчит

Comment: Так же пробовала внутренний ip другого приложения  192.168.0.61:58499, консоль так же молчит((

Comment: @Елизавета, обновил, должно работать.

Comment: Простите, я не заметила. Благодарю Вас! Все получилось!

Comment: Еще один вопросик, если вместо ip написать домен (и например без порта), это будет работать?

Comment: в текущей реализации нет, потому что класс IPGlobalProperties не возвращает доменные имена, он всегда явно возвращает IP-адреса.

Comment: А каким классом я смогла бы воспользоваться для доменных подключений?

Comment: Классом [Dns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns(v=vs.110).aspx), как то так примерно
`string howtogeek = "www.howtogeek.com";
IPAddress[] addresslist = Dns.GetHostAddresses(howtogeek);`

У него много методов для этого.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо Вам огромное!